# Insert JavaScript into Web-Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, web-part, script-webpart

I have inserted into my Home.aspx a list with Web-Parts like this:

[image]

Now I want to know how can I apply JavaScript to this list?

Note: I want to display an image depending of selected of one field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply JavaScript to your list by using **Script Editor Web-part(SEWP)**

[image]

Step 1: Edit the list page from top right gear/edit page.

Step 2: Add new web part and add a Script Editor to the page, under Media and Content.

Step 3: Add your JavaScript code.

Comment: When I press media and Content it don´t show me "Script Editor" Tab

Comment: You can use a Content Editor Web Part and do the same thing.  Also, it is better practice not to write you code directly into the editor.  Use the web part to reference a .js or .txt file with your code in it.

Comment: It dont appears because I don't have right permissions, there is how to activate it [Activate script capabilities](http://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000188451-prerequisite-1-enabling-scripting-capabilities)

Comment: Now a question. As I can see when we add an Script Editor it appears into web page. When I publish it, it appears or it hide?

Comment: When you save your Script Editor will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot looks like the Classic view. For this view you can use Client Side Rendering (JS Link) either for the field itself or for a List View Web Part (on a classic page).

In a modern view, you'll need to use a SharePoint Framework Field Customizer. However, these are still in preview and likely won't be available outside of developer tenants until the end of September or later.