# Google maps in SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, google-maps

I tried to embed Google map to a Sharepoint page by using the Incorporation Web Part, I past the code in the text zone, but the map doesn't work. 
I get an error that the content can not be displayed in a frame, when i click on "Open in a new tab", it gives me this message: "The Google Maps Embed API must be used in an iframe."

Here's the code generated by google maps :
`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d13291.921825883793!2d-7.549490730224608!3d33.60581155000001!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sma!4v1533914178152" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

I'm using Sharepoint Online

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SharePoint Modern page, please use Embed Code web part:

[image]

And then paste the code into the textbox right side:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have added the same iframe code in a **Script Editor** Webpart and it seems to be working as expected. Can you please tr the same. To embed the script editor :

1. Edit the page where you want to Embed the above mentioned code.
2. Insert a Webpart from Top and Select **Script Editor** from the section **Media and Content**.
3. Edit the web part and click on **Edit Snippet**.
4. Paste the needed iframe code and click on **Insert**.
5. Save the changes.

You can take the reference from below answer in order to insert **Script Editor**

[Insert JavaScript into Web-Part](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/224336/)

**Note :** You might need to activate Publishing feature in order to use it if not already activated before.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't find the Script Editor, or the section Media and Content... i didn't mention that I'm using SharePoint Online

Comment: - Click the settings cog in the upper right corner, and choose Edit Page

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

In **SharePoint online**, specifically in the `Modern Page`,  the best option that used to hold `IFrame` is **`Embed web part`**

**To add `Embed web part`**

- Click Edit at the top right of the page.
- Below an existing web part or under the title region, click  Circled plus sign used to add a modern web part to a page, and then select the Embed web part.
- In the toolbox on the right, add your code

  ```
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m10!1m8!1m3!1d13291.921825883793!2d-7.549490730224608!3d33.60581155000001!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sfr!2sma!4v1533914178152" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  ```

**Note:**

- The embed code must be iframe-based
- Only secure web sites can be embedded
- Not all websites allow their pages to be embedded, even when they are secure and use iframe-based embed code. so check with the website to see if they allow embedding.
- Site collection administrators can control whether users can embed content from external websites.
- No need to activate the publishing features! and before you do that for any other reason, I prefer to check this article first [MISSING “SAVE SITE AS A TEMPLATE” IN SHAREPOINT](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/28/how-to-save-site-as-template-for-publishing-sites/)

**For more details,** check [Use the Embed web part](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)